# Ruby: Retrieving values from method parameters

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out how I can create a method in Ruby where I can retrieve values from the method's parameters such as strings/integers.

For example, if this were a function coded in C, it might be done similar to this:

```
main()
{
    int value;
    GetAnIntegerValue(value);
    printf("The value is %d", value);
}

// The "value" integer variable is passed to it, and updated accordingly because of the use of the ampersand prior to the parameter
GetAnIntegerValue(&int value)
{
    value = 5;
}

// The output would be "The value is 5"
```

I think the term for this is pass by value but I'm not sure. My mind is a little vague on this area and I couldn't find many decent results.

Here's my example Ruby function, the array that the parameters are being assigned to is only local to the class which is the reason for this usage:

```
    def getRandomWordAndHint(&RandomWord, &RandomHint)
    randIndex = rand(7)
    RandomWord = EnglishLevel1Word[randIndex]
    RandomHint = EnglishLevel1Hint[randIndex]
end
```

Cheers!i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby is pass-by-value. Always. No exceptions. You cannot do pass-by-reference in Ruby.

What you *can* do, is put the object you want to change into some sort of mutable container:

```
class MutableCell
  attr_accessor :val

  def initialize(val)
    self.val = val
  end
end

def change_the_value(cell)
  cell.val = 5
end

value = MutableCell.new(42)

change_the_value(value)

value.val
# => 5
```

Of course, you can just use an `Array` instead of writing your own `MutableCell` class, this is just for demonstration.

However, mutable state is a bad idea in general, and mutating arguments passed to methods is a *really* bad idea especially. Methods know about their own object (i.e. `self`) and thus can safely modify it, but for *other* objects, that's generally a no-go.

Comment: I think I read a debate on SO in another question regarding what is meant by "pass-by-value". Would passing an object to a method still be pass-by-value?

Comment: @Keikoku: Ruby is pass-by-value. Always. No exceptions. It simply doesn't support pass-by-reference. Period. If it did, then this question wouldn't even arise.

Comment: I've always been under the impression that "pass-by-value" means the a copy of the argument is created within the scope of the method and doesn't affect the original data. Wouldn't passing an object around be passing by reference?

Comment: Pass-by-reference means that the reference *itself*, i.e. the *variable* in this case, is passed and can be manipulated. But that is not the case in Ruby. Ruby doesn't pass the reference, it passes the *value* obtained by dereferencing the reference. And that value *is* copied. It just so happens that the value is a pointer, and both the original pointer and the copied pointer point to the same object, so that modifications to that object can be seen by following either one of those two pointers. But *what* is being passed (an int, a pointer, an object) is irrelevant. How it's passed is.

Comment: If you are familiar with C, think about it this way: C is pass-by-value, but you can either pass the value or a pointer to the value. Regardless, it still is pass-by-value. In Ruby, you always pass the pointer, but the pointer is implicit.

Comment: So when someone says "pass-by-value" or "pass-by-reference" they are  strictly referring to how the programmer passes it, and has nothing to do with what the underlying implementation actually does. Because ya, I never have to think of how I want to pass things around in Ruby.